# Devexpress XAF. How apply autocomplete to field of string?

Tags: autocomplete, devexpress, xaf

I have class

```
[DomainComponent]
[DefaultClassOptions]
public interface IEmployee
{
    [XafDisplayName("Место рождения")]
    String PlaceOfBirth { get; set; }

}
```

When the user try to fill property "PlaceOfBirth" in Web GUI, I want to help him with standart autocomplete (like http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/ or same). Datasource of autocomplte is all value of "PlaceOfBirth" (distinct).

I already try many cases but not success. Is it possible?

PS: For now I use this advice https://documentation.devexpress.com/#Xaf/CustomDocument3116 but it not good for large collection :(

Answer (score 1):

Look at DevExpress support center there are solutions available.
http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Example/Details/E3325.

http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/K18561

Comment: The links i posted are asp.net webforms solutions same as XAF. So yes you can use them as solutions